# If $m,n\in Z$ then {$x\in Z: mn\mid x$}$\subset${$x\in Z:m|x$}$\cap${$x\in Z:n\mid x$}

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

If $m,n\in Z$ then {$x\in Z: mn\mid x$}$\subset${$x\in Z:m|x$}$\cap${$x\in Z:n\mid x$}

I know this is true, but I'm having trouble proving it

Answer (score 4):

Let $x$ such that $mn \mid x$; then $x=k(mn)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now by associativity and commutativity of the product $x=(km)n=(kn)m$, so $n \mid x$, $m \mid x$ respectively.

So now every $x$ that is divisible by $mn$ (so it's in the first set), it's both divisible by $m$ and $n$ (so it's in the second AND the third set). Being at the same time in two sets means that it belongs to the intersection.

Comment: How does this lead to mn|x being a subset $m|x \cap n|x$? I sort of see why but it's not apparent to me just yet.

Comment: $mn\Bbb Z\subseteq m\Bbb Z\cap n\Bbb Z\ $ by $\ mn\Bbb Z\subseteq m\Bbb Z,\,n\Bbb Z\ $ by $\ (mn)k = m(nk) = n(mk)\,$  by * is associative & commutative.  
 Recall $\,A\subseteq B\cap C\!\iff\! A\subseteq B,C\ $ is the *universal property* of intersection @user8714896